# What is wrong in this C++ code? Compile error: no matching function for call to ‘Test::Test(Test)’

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
 /* Class data members */
 public:
   Test(Test &t) { /* Copy data members from t*/}
   Test()        { /* Initialize data members */ }
};

Test fun()
{
  cout << "fun() Called\n";
  Test t;
  return t;
}

int main()
{
   Test t1;
   Test t2 = fun();
   return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with above C++ code? compiler throws following error.
`error: no matching function for call to ‘Test::Test(Test)’`

Answer (score 9):

You declared a copy constructor which requires a non-`const` lvalue. However, `fun()` returns a temporary and you can't bind a temporary to a non-`const` lvalue. You probably want to declare your copy constructor as

```
Test(Test const& t) { ... }
```